# Cmake_module_path not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 CMake Error at rpg_vikit/vikit_common/CMakeLists.txt:26 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  By not providing "FindSophus.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Sophus", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Sophus" with any
  of the following names:

    SophusConfig.cmake
    sophus-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Sophus" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Sophus_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Sophus"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/btaher20/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

After  that,I add

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

But  still  same  error

How  to  solve  it? Would  you any body  give link.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226795/cmake_module_path-not-found/) by [btaher20](https://answers.ros.org/users/25814/btaher20/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This means that the system dependency `Sophus` cannot be found and is thus not installed.
Check [the ROS wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/sophus) about how to install and try again.

It seems to be not configured correctly as a dependency in `vikit`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kilmarnock](https://answers.ros.org/users/1720/kilmarnock/) on 2017-04-07**:
exchange "Sophus" with "sophus" in any CMakeLists.txt file did it for me